# Having trouble getting emulator working using Android Studio and VSCode

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-emulator

I'm trying to get the android emulator working using Android studio. However I am getting an error that the ANDROID_HOME variable is set to a non-existing path.

Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: C:UsersLukeTAppDataLocalAndroidSdk[Photo of terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEgER.png)

I have Tried editing my bashrc file to include the proper path, I am using the path provided to me from Android studio. [Android SDK Location/path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvSUg.png). What exactly am I doing wrong here and where can I get the correct path?

Comment: Notice no backslashes in your path seen in the error message: `C:UsersLukeTAppDataLocalAndroidSdk`.  It's because backslash is an escape character.  You need to double every backslash to actually use them in paths.  ANDROID_HOME for example should be ``C:\\Users\\LukeT\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk``

Comment: Thanks yoduh, but I am still getting the same error unfortunately. It did fix the pathing but the error remains the same.  Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: C:\Users\LukeT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk